# Setting a NGINX Reverse Proxy to redirect traffic to a locally hosted NGINX server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a homelab with a bunch of applications running and I would like to access some of them from outside my network. Unfortunately, my ISP uses CGNAT, which means I don't get a real IP address. My solution for this was to rent a VPS and create a tunnel from the VPS to my homelab using ZeroTier, I then run a NGINX server on the VPS and redirect the requests to each application, with SSL provided by Certbot. This works as expected, but my VPS is slow and all the configs are done manually, while on my homelab I can run a NGINX Proxy Manager instance and make any changes really fast.

I've tried configuring like this on the VPS:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://homelab_zerotier_ip;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
    ssl_certificate ...
    ssl_certificate_key ...
    include ...
    ssl_dhparam ...
  }
```

But I get stuck in a redirect loop when I try to access my domain. I've also tried a bunch of different configurations, but I can't figure this one out. Any ideas?